# Is there a JQuery function to handle all mouse events at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, mouseevent

Is there a JQuery function (or plugin) to handle [all mouse events](http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events) at once?

For example, I can use `$("*").click()` to handle all click events in a page but I'm wondering if there's a function like:

```
$("*").mouseEvent("event type", function(){
    // handle all events based on their event type in one listener
});
```

Comment: `$('*')` is a horrible idea.  Just handle the root element.

Comment: @SLaks I'm trying to listen for a click event to any element in the page. How would you suggest doing it, and why is it a bad idea?

Comment: why would you want to do this? it would go off every time the mouse _moves_!

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Just out of curiosity @pennstatephil

Comment: You probably want to have one invisible element in front of everything, and handle all the events that happen on this element. Alternatively, you can use `$(document).click(function(){/*dostuff*/});` etc.

Comment: @jt0dd For example, you can use `$(document).on`. This way there is only one click event, and you let it bubble to the root document. Using `$(*).click` binds a click event listener on every single element on the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use delegated event handling to listen for all mouse events via event propagation.  You can pass multiple event names to the same event handler.  You can then look at event parameters when the event fires to see which type of event occurred on which DOM object.

```
$(document).on("mouseup mousedown click mousemove", function(e) {
    // e.type is the type of event
    // e.target is the element the event originally occured in
});
```

This has the advantage that it works for all elements in the page, even dynamic objects added AFTER you install the event handler.

The only disadvantage of doing it this way is that you usually cannot prevent the default behavior of the event because it may have already been processed by an event handler attached directly to the object (except you can prevent links from firing with `e.preventDefault()` because they apparently don't fire until after event propagation.

Comment: This is perfect. I've been missing out on event delegation. Huge advantage with handling dynamically generated content.

Comment: @jt0dd - yep delegated handling of events is hugely helpful with dynamic content.

Comment: And **again** with the links not firing until after event propagation, extremely useful. Answering questions that I haven't even asked yet, awesome.